# I have a list of a part of a filename, for each one I want to go through the files in a directory that matches that part and return the filename

Tags: python

So, let's say I have a directory with a bunch of filenames. 
for example:

Scalar Product or Dot Product (Hindi)-fodZTqRhC24.m4a
AP Physics C - Dot Product-Wvhn_lVPiw0.m4a
An Introduction to the Dot Product-X5DifJW0zek.m4a

Now let's say I have a list, of only the keys, which are at the end of the file names:

`['fodZTqRhC24', 'Wvhn_lVPiw0, 'X5DifJW0zek']`

How can I iterate through my list to go into that directory and search for a file name containing that key, and then return me the filename?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you show your latest attempt and explain what is currently not working for you? Show the exact error message, if any please.

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Comment: Ok you guys are right, I should try it myself first. Just had no clue how to try it, was thinking regex, but I'd need to pass a list of strings through it instead of a string. Anyway, let me spend some time trying to figure it out and get back to this if I get stuck.

Comment: Alright, I guess I was thinking of this harder than it had to be.

Answer (score 1):

I thought about it, I think I was making it harder than I had to with regex. Sorry about not trying it first. I have done it this way:

```
audio = ['Scalar Product or Dot Product (Hindi)-fodZTqRhC24.m4a',
'An Introduction to the Dot Product-X5DifJW0zek.m4a',
'AP Physics C - Dot Product-Wvhn_lVPiw0.m4a']   

keys = ['fodZTqRhC24', 'Wvhn_lVPiw0', 'X5DifJW0zek']   

file_names = []
for Id in keys:
    for name in audio:
        if Id in name:
            file_names.append(name)

combined = zip(keys,file_names)
combined
```

Comment: Take a look at the answer I posted. Your solution works, but it's contingent on you knowing the names of all of the files in the directory (because you hard coded the target words in `audio`). Look how I used `os.listdir()` to obtain the files.

Comment: Thanks a lot Harrison, I used ```file_list = !ls``` to convert the the directory into a list, but I think your way is better. Thanks a lot again!

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example:

ls: list of files in a given directory

names: list of strings to search for

```
import os
ls=os.listdir("/any/folder")
n=['Py', 'sql']
for file in ls:
   for name in names:
     if name in file:
       print(file)
```

Results :

```
.PyCharm50
.mysql_history
zabbix2.sql
.mysql
PycharmProjects
zabbix.sql
```

Comment: It should be `for name in n:`, because the name of the list is `n`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you know which directory that you will be looking in, you could try something like this:

```
import os

to_find = ['word 1', 'word 2']          # list containing words that you are searching for
all_files = os.listdir('/path/to/file') # creates list with files from given directory

for file in all_files:    # loops through all files in directory
    for word in to_find:  # loops through target words
        if word in file:
            print file    # prints file name if the target word is found
```

I tested this in my directory which contained these files:

```
Helper_File.py
forms.py
runserver.py
static
app.py
templates
```

... and i set `to_find` to `['runserver', 'static']`...

and when I ran this code it returned:

```
runserver.py
static
```

For future reference, you should make at least some sort of attempt at solving a problem prior to posting a question on Stackoverflow. It's not common for people to assist you like this if you can't provide proof of an attempt.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to do it that allows for a selection of weather to match based on placement of text.

```
import os
def scan(dir, match_key, bias=2):
    '''
        :0 startswith
        :1 contains
        :2 endswith
        '''

    matches = []
    if not isinstance(match_key, (tuple, list)):
        match_key = [match_key]

    if os.path.exists(dir):
        for file in os.listdir(dir):
            for match in match_key:
                if file.startswith(match) and bias == 0 or file.endswith(match) and bias == 2 or match in file and bias == 1:
                    matches.append(file)
                    continue
    return matches

print scan(os.curdir, '.py'
```

Comment: Might be better to replace `bias` with a `matcher` function, since magic numbers are bad. You can then do `scan(..., matcher=str.startswith)` and in your code just call `if matcher(file, match): ...`